# Apple ID could not sign in. Error: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

[image]

From the image, it said your Apple ID could not sign in.
When I try to click  'Retry' or Add new Apple ID, its show

> **"Couldn't communicate with a helper application"**.

I found some solution that is typing this command line in terminal

```
xcrun git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.com
xcrun git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
```

but its not work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Try to update your Xcode. It's a bug in Xcode 7. I found this solution. Try it once. I ran "softwareupdate --install --all" and it said that no updates are available
 
I then went into the app store and tried to update using the button and it worked, i can now also download other apps from the App Store

Comment: The solution you're giving worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mac ox version is low.I suggest you update your system to 10.11.1.Because I already resolved it.My xcode version is 7.1.1.

[image]